# Why can methods be overriden but attributes can't?

Tags: java, inheritance, this

I have a class

```
public class A {
    public String attr ="A attribute";
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(this+" , "+this.attr);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return("Object A");
    }
}
```

and another class that inherits from it

```
public class B extends A{
    public String attr = "B attribute";
    public void method() {
        super.method();
    }
    public String toString() {
        return("Object B");
    }
}
```

Note that the `method()` of `B` is simply a wrapper for `method()` of `A`.

When I run the following code

```
B b = new B();
b.method();
```

I get `Object B , A attribute` as output which means that, `this` and `this.attr` accessed different things. Why is that the case?

Shouldn't `System.out.println(this)` refer to the `toString()` method of class `A` ?

Comment: A modern IDE will have the possibility to show a warning on the second definition of `attr` that it 'shadows' a similarly named field of a superclass.

Comment: @Noah why did you revert the edited question name? I think the edited title `Why can methods be overriden but attributes can't` described the content of the question better than the current one. This is important for all other people looking for an answer to their question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By declaring a method with a same name as parent class, you *override* it, that is, replace the original behaviour. But if you declare a field with a same name, you effectively *hide* it, making it inaccessible from that subclass, but only by `super.field`. See oracle docs on [variable hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html), as well as using the [keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html). Note that it is not recommended to use variable hiding, as it creates exactly the kind of confusion you're experiencing.

By calling `super.method()`, printing `this` results in calling the `toString` method, which was in fact overridden - so that's the reason why it prints "Object B", as you've called the method on an instance of B. But the `this` in `this.attr` actually refers to the parent object, as you're calling the `method` from the parent class (by `super.method()`).